# Instantiate thrift-generated object in Angular 7

Tags: angular, thrift

We are using thrift-generated objects in many languages, but I can't figure out how to instantiate the objects in js/ts.

Here is the generated ts module Network_Test_types.d.ts :

```
//
// Autogenerated by Thrift Compiler (0.12.0)
//
// DO NOT EDIT UNLESS YOU ARE SURE THAT YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING
//

declare module Rockit {
  class TestObject {
    stringValue: string;

      constructor(args?: { stringValue: string; });
  }
}
```

Here is the generated thrift js source Network_Test_types.js:

```
  //
  // Autogenerated by Thrift Compiler (0.12.0)
  //
  // DO NOT EDIT UNLESS YOU ARE SURE THAT YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING
  //

  if (typeof Rockit === 'undefined') {
    Rockit = {};
  }
  Rockit.TestObject = function(args) {
    this.stringValue = null;
    if (args) {
      if (args.stringValue !== undefined && args.stringValue !== null) {
        this.stringValue = args.stringValue;
      } else {
        throw new Thrift.TProtocolException(Thrift.TProtocolExceptionType.UNKNOWN, 'Required field stringValue is unset!');
      }
    }
  };
  Rockit.TestObject.prototype = {};
  Rockit.TestObject.prototype.read = function(input) {
    input.readStructBegin();
    while (true) {
      var ret = input.readFieldBegin();
      var ftype = ret.ftype;
      var fid = ret.fid;
      if (ftype == Thrift.Type.STOP) {
        break;
      }
      switch (fid) {
        case 1:
        if (ftype == Thrift.Type.STRING) {
          this.stringValue = input.readString().value;
        } else {
          input.skip(ftype);
        }
        break;
        case 0:
          input.skip(ftype);
          break;
        default:
          input.skip(ftype);
      }
      input.readFieldEnd();
    }
    input.readStructEnd();
    return;
  };

  Rockit.TestObject.prototype.write = function(output) {
    output.writeStructBegin('TestObject');
    if (this.stringValue !== null && this.stringValue !== undefined) {
      output.writeFieldBegin('stringValue', Thrift.Type.STRING, 1);
      output.writeString(this.stringValue);
      output.writeFieldEnd();
    }
    output.writeFieldStop();
    output.writeStructEnd();
    return;
  };
```

I tried importing the module into a component like this

```
import { Rockit } from '../assets/gen-js/Network_Test_types';
```

but angular looks for a file called Network_Test_types.d.js instead of what I have with a .ts extension.

So my questions are a) what do I import and b) how do I construct the object?

Comment: Did you check [the test server](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/ts/test/test.ts) and [test client](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/ts/test/phantom-client.ts) sources?

Comment: Thanks for that reference. It did have a clue in it and I have gotten a bit further. I will add a post about where I am now.

Comment: They are using the phantom library that has an injection step that I tried to emulate with "var Thrift = require('../../assets/thrift.js');". So now the Thrift object is defined. But when I do "var transport = new Thrift.Transport(...)" in complains that Thrift.Transport is not a constructor.

Comment: Great, but that's also where my wisdom ends. I'd recommend to ask that question on the mailing lists if no answer comes in here.